# Detecting a spike in an input signal using Java

Tags: java, accelerometer

I'm working on a project where, I need to control the mouse cursor by some accelerometer input. I'm using Java and have already completed the data collection part and I can move the mouse according to accelerometer input successfully.

I also need to support mouse click events which are triggered by a sudden movement. So; this sudden movement creates a spike in the input signal (a wide one, not just single point). How can I detect such a spike using Java?

Comment: How can you detect such a spike in the first place, regardless of implementation language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A properly tuned high-pass filter could do it, depending on your application. Really simple, 1 line of code.

[High-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter)